# jQuery add input to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

HTML

```
<form id = "form1">
     <div class = "fields">
          <div class="add">Add</div>
     </div>

    </form>

    <form id = "form2">
     <div class = "fields">
          <div class="add">Add</div>
     </div>

    </form>
```

JS

```
 $('.add').live('click', function() {

     $('<input type="text" value="test">').appendTo('.fields');
 })
```

I want add add input only to this form from where is clicked button not to both, how to limit insert ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the form of the button and then append the input control.

like this:

```
$('.add').live('click', function() {

      $(this).closest("form").append('<input type="text" value="test">');

 })
```

Answer (score 2):

`live` is deprecated, use `.on` for event delegation. And if this form isn't dynamic, just use  a handler and reference `this`:

```
$(".add").click(function() {
    var input = $('<input type="text" value="test">');
    $(this).parent(".fields").append(input);
});
```

Comment: If the OP is using an older version of jQuery `on()` will not be available.

Comment: @JayBlanchard -- True - either way, if the form isn't dynamic there's no reason for `.on` or `.live` :D